# property of asymptotic rate of convergence of gradient decent algorithm on a quadratic form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, gradient-descent

Geven a quadratic form $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+x^Tb+a$, where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. We use gradient decent to compute the global min by $x_n=x_{n-1}-\triangledown f(x_{n-1})$ and define $d(x_n)=\|x_n-x^*\|$. Let $A=PDP^T$ be the eigen decomposition of $A$.

Given appropriate learning rate $\alpha$, we get convergence of $d(x_n)$ to $0$. Where

$d(x_n)=((x_o)^T+b^TPD^{-1}P^T)(I-\lambda PD^TP)^n(I-\lambda PDP^T)^n(x_0+PD^{-1}P^Tb)$. Is this correct?

now define $\rho=exp(\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{2k}ln(d(x_k))$, we want to show that for any choice of hyperparameter values(is there other hyperparameters for gradient decent except for learning rate?), there is constants $k_0 \geq 0$ and $C >0$ such that $$d(x_k)\leq C\rho^{2k}, \forall k \geq k_0$$.

Answer (score 1):

This holds more generally for strongly convex functions (not just quadratic). See the proof in Yaron Singer's notes: https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~yaron/AM221-S16/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture9.pdf

(You are correct, the learning rate is the only hyperparameter.)

Comment: I don't understand the paper, I think they have some typos. I don't undertand what is a strongly convex function? Can you explain the definition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions

Comment: Sorry in the definition of their strongly convex function, does $H_f$ mean the hessian? so there exist m<M such that the hessian is greater than or equals to mI and less  than or equals to MI, But how do you compare matrices?

Comment: In this context, for matrices $A$ and $B$, $A\leq B$ is understood to mean that $B-A$ is positive semidefinite (also written $B-A \geq 0$).

Comment: Can you add an outline of the proof? So that it'll be easier for me to understand the paper. Foer example, what result is used to get what result to get the bound that we want to prove?

Comment: What does $b \in [x,y]$ mean when they are vector? is it the norm of $b$ is between norm of $x$ and norm of $y$?

Comment: I believe in this case it means that $b$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $y$.